# Idiom- once (in) a blue moon

Tags: prepositions, idioms

Opportunities like that come once a blue moon.

Opportunities like that come once **in** blue moon.

I did a little searching on the internet and found out the correct phrase/idiom is the second one, but if we took the preposition out like i did with the first sentence, would it still be grammatically correct? Is the first sentence grammstically correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom is

> once in ***a*** blue moon

with an article, as in the question title.

It is an idiom, and idioms when used differently do not sound right.

In any case, the first example makes it seem as though what happens is a *regular* occurrence, to coincide with *every* astronomical [blue moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_moon), as in "the bills come once a month."

But the phrase [**once in a blue moon**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/once_in_a_blue_moon) means **rarely**, if at all. So your first example is grammatically correct, but means that opportunities come regularly, whereas the usual idiom means quite the opposite.